# RadGridView (Telerik) обновление данных

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

Каким образом можно обновить данные в radGridView, при передачи отредактированного объекта в radGridView.DataSource = editedOject?

Answer (score 0):

```
radGridView.DataSource = editedOject
radGridView.Refresh();
```

Comment: Если обновлять таким способом, данные вообще не отображаются.